# Average of values from a column/ Skip lines (textscan)

Tags: matlab, file-io, textscan

I have a .txt file which looks like this:

```
******text*******
(30 lines containing text and *)
******text*******

a b c
a b c
a b c
a b c
a b c
a b c
a b c
```

(I'm creating a plot with a as x and b and c as y1 and y2)

How do I skip those 30 lines with textscan? I had this but it didn't work:

```
[x y1 y2] = textscan('file_name.txt', '%f %f %f', 30);
```

And more: how to I make the average of the values of third column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I skip certain lines from being processed?

You have a few options regarding line skipping:

- **If the number of lines are always static, and always in the beginning of the file:**

  Pass `HeaderLines` with a value of N, with N being the numbers you'd like not to process.

  `[x y1 y2] = textscan ('file_name.txt', '%f %f %f', 'HeaderLines', 30 + 2);`
- **If all lines start with the same character string**

  *Pass `CommentStyle` with a value of ABC where `ABC` is the comment style.

  If all lines to skip start with `*`, pass `'*'` to `textscan`.

  `[x y1 y2] = textscan ('file_name.txt', '%f %f %f', 'CommentStyle', '*');`

---

#### How do I get the average of some array?

To get the average of some array, use [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html):

```
y1_average = mean (y1);
```

---

**Documentation of `textscan`**:

- [Read formatted data from text file or string - MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html)

**Documentation of `mean`**

- [Average or mean value of array - MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html)

Comment: Textscan only has 1 output which would be a 3 element cell array in the example which would contain x, y1, and y2.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many lines to skip use `HeaderLines` parameter in [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) function:

```
[x y1 y2] = textscan('file_name.txt', '%f %f %f', 'HeaderLines',30);
```

When you use integer argument after the formatting string, it means you want to apply the formatting string this number of times (number of lines to read in your case). So it's opposite to what you want.

To get the average use [MEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html) function:

y2_avg = mean(y2);